# Show Rails Simple Form view with dashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm trying to achieve something that is probably very simple but I can't figure out the correct way to do it. Using Ruby on Rails and the Simple Form gem I have an input for bank sort code:

```
<%= simple_form_for @direct_debit, url: direct_debit_payment_path do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :bank_sort_code, placeholder: "6 digit sort code", id: "Sort-code", label: "Bank Sort Code" %>
<% end %>
```

[image: Bank sort code in ruby on rails]

I would simply like this to display as the client types in a normal bank sort code format: 12-34-56.

Also, I have a model validation to check that the field has a maximum of 6 numbers after sending the form, however I would like the client to literally not be able to type more than 6. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `maxlength` attribute for second part of you question

```
= f.input :bank_sort_code, placeholder: "6 digit sort code", 
  id: "Sort-code", label: "Bank Sort Code",
  input_html: { maxlength: 6 }
```

And for beautify input value format you can try [jquery maskedinput plugin](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput)

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#Sort-code").mask("99-99-99", {placeholder: "6 digit sort code" });
});
```

But if you'll use it, you should check your `maxlength` input attribute.

Comment: Excellent thank you, both answers were perfect to solve my problem ! The only thing I really changed was the placeholder to :
{placeholder: "  -  -  " }

Comment: I was glad to help )